# How to retrieve shared iCloud Link

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, sharing

iOS offers to share pictures via iCloud Link. I hand-picked 15 photos and shared them with another iPhone user via iMessage. Now I'd like to share these 15 photos further with an Android user.

How can I retrieve the previously created iCloud Link? In the Messages app, when I long-press and choose Copy, it only copies the selected picture. I'm looking for a way how to copy the iCloud Link to be able to further share all 15 pics.

Is this possible? Or do I have to hand-pick those 15 pics again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your Photos app tap on the ‘For You’ tab bar at the bottom of your screen. You can locate recently shared iCloud links and photos here. However, you cannot access any photos shared over 30 days ago.